# Android NumberPicker greater value appear above

Tags: java, android

I was wondering how do you change the display of numbers in NumberPicker in Android.

Currently all greater values will be displayed below the selected value, and all lower values will be displayed above. This makes no sense to me, and I would like to have the greater values be on top, while the lower ones be on bottom.

```
So instead of:
1 <~Current Selected Value
2
3

It should look
3
2
1 <~Current Selected Value
```

Do I need to make my own NumberPicker to fix this? Also why do they have the greater values on the bottom?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a string of the values going the direction you want. Not sure if this is how you wanted to do it, but it will work.

```
int min = 1;
int max = 10;
String values[] = new String[(max-min+1)];
for(int i = 0;(i+min) <= max;i++) {
    values[i]= Integer.toString((max-i));
}

NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.picker);
picker.setMaxValue(max-min);
picker.setMinValue(0);
picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
picker.setDisplayedValues(values);
```

If you want to get the value, you can either parse the string or you can get the value of (max-SelectedIndex+min)